# CSS display table - How to have 2 fixed and one flexible column

Tags: css

I have a table build with div's and css to make it responsive. There are three columns - Position, Description and Price - each of them has a input field inside.

Have a look at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZKP3j/3/

The -Tags have display: none; since the will be used on small screens with css media-queries. So you can just ignore it.

How can I change my css that the first (item1) and third (item3) column input fields has the fixed width they have now and the seconde one (item2) with the description should expand to the remaining space.

Just one example of the item2:

```
    <div class="item2">
        <label>Description</label>
        <input type="text" name="description" value="The best DVD on earth" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a 100% width to the item2 input will stretch it to fit the available space.

CSS

```
.item2 input {
    width:100%;
}
```

You may also need to adjust your item3 class to create the spacing shown between item1 and item2.

```
.item3 {
  width: 98px;
  padding-left:8px;
}
```

Working example here - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZKP3j/5/)

Comment: `.item2` is anyway 100%. Only `input` has a default size which need to be grown.

Answer (score 1):

```
.item2 input {
    width: 100%; 
}

.item3 input {
    width: 90px;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0 0 0 8px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uL9zt/)